# gsub ignore case on matching but output should follow original case

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to match `log-in` regardless of its case but the resulting matches for `log-in` (`with ignore case`) should follow its original case.

```
txt <- 'log-in LOG-in LOG-IN LOG IN log-on LOG-on LOG-ON LOG ON 23-2'
have <- gsub(pattern = 'log[ -]in',replacement ='login' ,x = txt,ignore.case = T)
have 
> "login login login login log-on LOG-on LOG-ON LOG ON 23-2"

want
> "login LOGin LOGIN LOGIN log-on LOG-on LOG-ON LOG ON 23-2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub(pattern = '(log)[ -](in)', replacement ='\\1\\2' , x = txt, ignore.case = T)
[1] "login LOGin LOGIN LOGIN log-on LOG-on LOG-ON LOG ON 23-2"
```

This works with backreference: `\\1`refers back to the first capture group `(log)` and 'remembers' it in its exact form (including case), `(log)`, while `\\2` refers back to the second capture group `(in)`

Comment: Also looking forward to read your book, looks like something I need while playing with my text data

Comment: Oh, that's nice! Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

One way is to name `log` and `in` part as a group and use "\1" and "\2" in the substitution text.

```r
txt <- 'log-in LOG-in LOG-IN LOG IN log-on LOG-on LOG-ON LOG ON 23-2'
gsub("(log)[ -](in)", "\\1\\2", txt, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: I haven't:p  Yours came in while I was doing a final check.  I don't mind deleting this (or having someone delete this) because the codes are exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you wanted to do this for both login and logout in one quick like you could just replace the '-' or ' ' when it is following a 'g'.

```
want <- gsub(x = txt, pattern = "(?<=g)[- ]", '', perl = TRUE,ignore.case = T)
```

if you did just want login add a look ahead too.

```
want <- gsub(x = txt, pattern = "(?<=g)[- ](?=i)", '', perl = TRUE,ignore.case = T)
```

Comment: Yes, but this wouldn't scale should there are some false positive strings which has the same pattern as `-` followed by `g`.

Comment: change it to '(?<=log)' then